# Does html charset apply to the markup or the content or both?

Tags: html, http, character-encoding

I'm wondering if something like this:

Content-Type: text/html; charset=<some encoding>

means that the markup tags are also in <some encoding> or if it only refers to the content.

Full example:

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Super_Awesome_Encoding">
</head>
<body>
    Some content!
</body>
</html>

Are the markup tags <html>, <body>, etc encoded as Super_Awesome_Encoding or just the string "Some content!" ?

Is there a difference if the charset is set via an http header such as:

Content-Type: text/html; charset=Super_Awesome_Encoding

?

Comment: That's not a complete example. Please add the full row you're thinking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It refers to the entire file (note that it is a claim and that it is possible for the actual encoding to differ, this is likely to lead to undesired effects).

Comment: So to be clear, in the above example, the markup is also in Super_Awesome_Encoding ?

Comment: Quentin, ASCII is not a subset of EBCDIC or UTF-16 for example. In an UTF-16 encoded document, each markup character must appear as two bytes, one of which is zero byte, which would be taken as NUL U+0000 if interpreted as ASCII.